# navigation.dangerouslyGetParent is not a function How can i fix this problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i am facing a error callednavigation.dangerouslyGetParent is not a function and its undefined so how can i fix this issue? what can i write in place of dangerouslyGetParent() if its not a function?

```
` useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = navigation.dangerouslyGetParent().addListener('tabPress', e => {
            console.log("TAB PRESSED");
            if(refPosts.current){
                refPosts.current.scrollToIndex({ animated: true, index: 0 });
            }
        });`
```

Answer (score 5):

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/#dropped-dangerously-from-dangerouslygetparent-and-dangerouslygetstate

> **React v6**
> Dropped dangerously from `dangerouslyGetParent` and `dangerouslyGetState​`     The `dangerouslyGetParent` and
> `dangerouslyGetState` methods on the navigation prop are useful in
> many scenarios, and sometimes necessary. So we dropped the dangerously
> prefix to make it clear that it's safe to use. Now you can use
> `navigation.getParent()` and `navigation.getState()`.